# SharePoint web site asking for authentication in iOS and Apple mobile phones

Tags: 2013, anonymous-authentication, mobile, apple-ios

We published our web application to the internet and it has publishing featureless enabled.

I edited the `compact.browser` file in this path:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\<web application>\App_Browser\compat.browser
```

from: `<capability name="isMobileDevice" value="true" />`

to : `<capability name="isMobileDevice" value="false" />`

In Android version it working fine but in iPhone and Safari browsers in iPhone some pages are asking for authentication.

When a user browses in an iOS device it's redirecting to the `layouts/15/mobile/mblwpa.aspx` page, and I have also disabled the `Disable-SPFeature -Identity "ViewFormPagesLockDown" -URL https://xxx`

Comment: Did the Android version work after updating the compat.browser file ?

Comment: yes android version working fine

Comment: Read this if helpfull http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38086/sharepoint-repeatedly-prompting-ipad-users-for-credentials