# Remembering credentials on Safari browser (IOS device)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, apple-ios

I enter to a Sharepoint site on-premise correctly from Safari browser on an IOS device, but when I close and re-open the browser ask me again credentials without remember them and does not give me the option to save.
I tried accessing a Sharepoint Online and ask me. The problem is with on-premise site and probably it is the authentication mode used, NTLM.

Does anyone know any workaround to avoid having to enter credentials every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup Web Application Proxy (WA-P) to handle the authentication mechanism as the iOS devices don't have cached credentials capability since they are not domain devices. So when a user hits the SharePoint On-Prem site, they are prompted by WA-P for credentials and then WA-P would securely handle the authentication and then handoff the content rendering to SharePoint server.

It would require some SharePoint admin efforts, but overall it's a very rugged , secure, tried and tested solution to handle BYOD issues.

Web Application Proxy is basically a simplified TMG Server; it’s without a lot of the functionality TMG Server has but on the plus side it gives a real quick way of setting up a reverse-proxy for a web application like SharePoint. There’s no firewall functionality as before outside of what comes with Windows Server by default; the beauty of this role is its simplicity.

Web Application Proxy has two modes of authentication for authenticating against whatever web-app you’re publishing; pass-through and ADFS. The principal is the same though; it’ll act as a safety buffer between your internal SharePoint systems and the outside world as no traffic will reach SharePoint unless it’s been authenticated 1st.

Overall, the flow would be something like below:

[image]

References -

[Publishing SharePoint with Windows Server 2012 R2 Web Application Proxy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2014/12/10/publishing-sharepoint-with-windows-server-2012-r2-web-application-proxy/)

[SharePoint Server and Web Application Proxy – continued](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2015/07/01/sharepoint-server-and-web-application-proxy-continued/)

[SharePoint repeatedly prompting iPad users for credentials](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38086/sharepoint-repeatedly-prompting-ipad-users-for-credentials)

[Authenticating to SharePoint from iOS devices](https://paddleshift.wordpress.com/2013/03/01/authenticating-to-sharepoint-from-iphone-and-ipad/)

Comment: I agree to your idea in implementing an authentication-proxy in front of SharePoint. But you should not recommend TMG. This product is discontinued. Even the TMG-successor UAG is already discontinued. So we should recommend him to implement a WebApplicationProxy.

Comment: My bad, you are correct. I had answered based on one of my old client's use cases. Didn't know it was discontinued. Thanks a lot. Based on your comments, I have updated the answer.